# Why do some terms vanish in first-order perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, perturbation-theory

In [first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29#First_order_corrections)-order [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29), we usually express the first-order perturbation in the  eigenket of the perturbed Hamiltonian in the basis of the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H_{0}$:
$$
\left|b\right>~=~\sum_{n} {b_{n} \left|E_{n}\right>}
\,,$$
where $\left|b\right>$ is the first-order change in the perturbed eigenket and the $\left|E_{n}\right>$ are the eigenkets of $H_{0}$.

**Questions:**

1. In the non-degenerate case, how do you show that $b_{0}=0$?  Here, $b_{0}$ is the coefficient corresponding to the "initial" eigenket; that is, the zeroth-order one in the expansion.
2. Is it also the case that $b_0=0$ in the degenerate case?
3. If $b_0=0$ in the degenerate case, how do you show that if the initial eigenket belongs to a degenerate subspace, then not only $b_{0}=0$, but $b_{j}=0$ for all the $b_{j}$s corresponding to the eigenkets of $H_{0}$ in that degenerate subspace?

---

For the first point, I've seen a proof that you can take it to be so in Binney & Skinner's book, but it seems to assume that the perturbed ket calculated in the usual way has normalization equal to $1$, at least to first-order in the perturbing parameter, and I don't see how is this justified. Here's the excerpt:
$\hspace{70px}$[image: Proof for 1st point].

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Box 10.1 and Wikipedia seem to fully answer OP's subquestion 1 (and using essentially the same proof).

Comment: True, but they don't seem to justify the assumption that $\langle E | E \rangle=1$ to first order in the perturbing parameter.

Comment: $\langle E | E \rangle\equiv 1$ and $\langle E_0 | E_0 \rangle\equiv 1$ hold by definition to all orders in the perturbation parameter.

Comment: Hm, sorry I think you're right.

Comment: I am happy with my first subquestion now. However, my second question is still unanswered.

Comment: To give more detail. As far as I can see the terms I'm talking about, that is the $\frac{\langle E_{1} | V | E_{2} \rangle}{E-{2}-E_{1}} | E_{1} \rangle$ for two degenerate states gives you $\frac{0}{0}$! So what do you do with this?

Comment: I meant $E_{2}-E_{1}$ in the denominator above.

Comment: @nat Please, stop adding extra space around equal signs. It is a discouraged practice. The recommended spacing is the default one, and it is automatically managed by mathjax (with `=` being a binary operator). It is great that you want to fix posts, but please, adding `~` around `=` is not an improvement, but the other way around. Thanks.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform It'd be more helpful if you could provide a reference or some sort of reasoning.  For example, when you say "_discouraged practice_" and "_recommended spacing_", are you referring to a style guide?

Comment: @Nat Have a look at e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55512 When it comes to (La)TeX, the rule of thumb is: the default setting is the recommended one. Chaps gave it some thought and they decided what the best setting is. And they made it the default one. If more spacing were better, they would have defined the `=` operator to have it.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I'd have to disagree with the idea that $\mathrm{\TeX}$'s formatting is adequate; instead, I'd say that it's a primitive system that lacks context awareness and has been kept around due to inertia.  For example, I end up replacing a lot of `\langle`'s with `\left<`'s, etc., since `\langle` is a character and not a structural element; likewise, `=` is a character and not a structural element, the conflation of which seems crass to me.  Still, I'll try to check into if you're right about the expected norms, since it'd make sense to format stuff as folks expect.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I've been trying it out, but in many cases it's just too ugly.  That said, since you've brought this up twice, I'm curious about your reasoning; I mean, $\mathrm{\TeX}$ isn't context-aware (beyond very minimal local hacks, e.g. `x=x` can render differently than `x{=}x`), so it's literally incapable of making informed decisions about spacing based on the operands' size.  Additionally, I've noticed other users, including mods, use `~=~` as well since you've brought it up.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform (Actually, this is probably the wrong place to discuss it.  Please feel free to ping me in the SE.Physics chatroom!)